# Suppose $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ and $p$ is limit point show be example that this conclusion cannot be made

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question:** Suppose $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ and $p$ is limit point of $E$. If $\lim\limits_{x\to p}f(x)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in E$, then prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to p}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\infty$. Show by example that this conclusion can not be made if the condition $f(x)>0$ is not there.

I made example with $\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}1/x= \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0-}1/x= -\infty$
and... don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply it like this.

Put $E=\mathbb{R}$ and define $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x$. Choose $p=0$.

Clearly $0$ is a limit point of $E=\mathbb{R}$. Also it is not case that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Observe that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x=0$, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}\frac{1}{x}= \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0-}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0-}\frac{1}{x}= -\infty$. Therefore that conclusion can not be made if the condition $f(x)>0$ is not hold.